# Where 'index' property is defined, as Repeater is used to instantiate an array of items, each them can access the index

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I guess **index** is an attached property, but where is it defined and why accessing the **index** is not as `ListView.isCurrentItem`?

From the official documentation, [description of **delegate** property of Repeater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html):

> Delegates are exposed to a read-only index property that indicates the index of the delegate within the repeater.

I am more confused. Why are delegates exposed to a property, and by what operation does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`index` is not an attached property, it's a context property.

Since `Repeater` is instantiating the delegates itself, it can provide a custom context when doing so.

In this context you have `index`, a property for each role of your model (or `modelData` if it's a model without roles) and a `model` object property containing all the previously mentionned properties.
The `model` object is there to be able to access the other properties with a more qualified name, to avoid shadowing.
For example if your source model has a `text` role and your delegate has a `text` property, doing `text: text` won't go very far. To resolve this you can do `text: model.text`.

To summarize, your delegate has access to those context properties:

For a model without roles (`QStringList`, `QObjectList`, a JS array, an integer, ...):

- `index`
- `modelData`
- `model`

  - `.index`
  - `.modelData`

For a model with roles (a c++ `QAbstractListModel`, `ListModel`, ...):

- `index`
- `role1`
- `role2`
- ...
- `model`

  - `.index`
  - `.role1`
  - `.role2`
  - ...

Why `ListView` is using attached properties such as `ListView.isCurrentItem` and not context properties is because `ListView` doesn't directly instantiates its delegates. It uses `QQmlDelegateModel` internally (`Repeater` uses it too). It is `QQmlDelegateModel` that expose the index and role context properties, but it isn't aware of `ListView` specific properties, so `ListView` has to expose them via attached propeties afterwards.

Comment: Thanks first. And if my `ListView`'s delegate contains a `Repeater` inside it, how the `Repeater`'s delegate access the `ListView`'s delegate **index**.

Comment: May I could define a custom property, if I can access the index already existed rather than this? By the way, where did you know about these, source code?

Comment: I guess what you are asking is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828379/is-there-any-possibility-to-reach-the-index-of-an-outer-qml-repeater-from-the-in .
I learned this by messing a lot about model stuff in QML, reading source code, reading other comments and keeping an eye open :)

Comment: It seems that there is only this way as I mentioned. Thank you for your help without reservation. Quiet clearly!

Answer (score 0):

The `index` property is a normal property that can be used in a delegate and will be different for each time the delegate is repeated (by `Repeater`, `ListView` and many more)

With this in mind you can do handy things, like highlighting the current item:

```
ListView {
    id: list
    model: 5 //instantiate the delegate 5 times

    delegate: Button {
        highlighted: list.currentIndex == index

        onClicked: list.currentIndex = index
    }
}
```