# How to get parent Repeater index in nested Repeaters?

Tags: qt, indexing, qml, qt6

I had the following problem:

```
Repeater {
    id: parentRepeater
    model: Array(10).fill([""])

    Repeater {
        model: modelData
        
        Label {
            text: index // gets only the child index, not parent
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to print out the parent index but with pure `index` it shows only the child's, as it should do.

Is there anyway to make it show the parent's index?

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there any possibility to reach the index of an outer QML Repeater from the inner one (they are nested)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828379/is-there-any-possibility-to-reach-the-index-of-an-outer-qml-repeater-from-the-in) ***|*** [Qml Repeater with ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308872/qml-repeater-with-ids).

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub The first one is the most related however its solution in this case is incomplete in my opinion as it lacks `modelData` nesting and it doesn't show the data being operated on.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution is the following by making `parentRepeaterIndex` property having the parent `index` value:

```
Repeater {
    id: parentRepeater
    model: Array(10).fill([""])

    Repeater {
        model: modelData
        property int parentRepeaterIndex: index

        
        Label {
            text: parentRepeaterIndex
        }
    }
}
```